# How to access redux store outside of a component in React + ASP.NET Core + TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, redux

I have some sort of experience on React but I'm super new to using Redux. However, Visual Studio 2017 has a built in **React + Redux** template under **.NET Core 2.0**.

**Some info of my environment:**

- visual studio 2017
- react 15.6.1
- typescript 2.4.1
- redux 3.7.1
- react-redux 5.0.5

The project sets up everything for me and I can run it without any errors so far so good.

I only have a simple question. Please check this image ->

[image]

When I click on the counter button

1. It should update the counter (By default done by asp.net)
2. The same number should be displayed next to the 'WebApplication10' header

eg: **WebApplication10(3)**

The goal of this attempt is to understand how to access redux store from a whole different component.

I tried something on the **NavMenu** component like this:

```js
type CounterProps =
    CounterStore.CounterState
    & typeof CounterStore.actionCreators
    & RouteComponentProps<{}>;
```

and modified the class definition line just like this

```js
export class NavMenu extends React.Component<CounterProps, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>//rest of the code</div>;
    }
}
```

Doing this only gives me a small error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Layout.tsx:9:21 
TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NavMenu> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & R...'.
```

I hope you have understood my question and pardon me if I have not provided every detail to solve this issue. Please do let me know if you need anything else.

Thank you for reading.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since we need to wrap a container component around the raw `NavMenu`, the most straightforward way is to rename your raw `NavMenu` to `NavMenuComponent`

   ```
   class NavMenuComponent extends React.Component<CounterProps, {}> {
       public render() {
           return <div className='main-nav'>
                   <div className='navbar navbar-inverse'>
                   <div className='navbar-header'>
                       <!-- ...  -->
                       <Link className='navbar-brand' to={ '/' }>WebApplication10 <span>{this.props.count}</span></Link>
                   </div>
                   <!-- ...  -->
               </div>
           </div>;
       }
   }
   ```

   and then export the new wrapped `NavMenu`:

   ```
   export const NavMenu = connect(
       (state: ApplicationState) => state.counter, 
       CounterStore.actionCreators                 
   )(NavMenuComponent);

   export default NavMenu;
   ```

[image]

2. Just as a side note, you don't need to add types such as `typeof actionCreators` or `RouteComponentProps` :

   ```
   type CounterProps =
       CounterStore.CounterState
       & typeof CounterStore.actionCreators
       & RouteComponentProps<{}>;
   ```

   Since the `NavMenu` only reads the `CounterState.count`, no extra actions or routes are required. Simply use the following code to define `CounterProps`

   ```
    type CounterProps =
       CounterStore.CounterState;
   ```

   If you would like to add custom actions in the future, simply add actions as you like :

   ```
   type CounterProps =
       CounterStore.CounterState
       & your action type;
   ```